# How to return a boolean if array index values are equal to a x & y values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, payload

Is there a way to check if array `this.state.allBooks` contains both `id:552` and  `name:'book2'` in the same index and return either true or false... I want to avoid using a for loop if possible.

```
// Array this.state.allBooks 
O:{id:133, name:'book1'}
1:{id:552, name:'book2'}
2:{id:264, name:'book3'}
```

previously I've done something similar to the below code, but since array `this.state.allBooks` has an id and a name I'm not sure what approach to take.

```
let boolValue = this.state.allBooks.includes(/* check if it includes a single value*/)

//Desired output 
// 1.0) Does this.state.allBooks include both id:552 and name:'book2' in the same index ? 
// a)   if yes return true ... should be yes since both id:552 and name:'book2' are part of the same index '1'
// b)   if no return false
```

Comment: You will need some kind of loop, there is no way around it. The best way is probably `Array#some`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can just use JavaScript's [method `some` of the array class](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_some.asp). Some will return true if any of the elements in the array match the given predicate so the following code should do the trick:

```
let boolValue = this.state.allBooks.some(bookObject => bookObject.id === 552 && bookObject.name === 'book2');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.find` to search for the entry. However, do note that internally the implementation of Array methods that involves searching and filtering always involve some kind of `for` loop anyway.

```js
const data1 = [{id:133, name:'book1'},{id:552, name:'book2'},{id:264, name:'book3'}];
const found1 = data1.find(({ id, name }) => id === 552 && name === 'book2');
console.log(found1);    // { id: 552, name: 'book2' }
console.log(!!found1);  // true

// Let's mutate the entry so it will not be found, for testing
const data2 = [{id:133, name:'book1'},{id:999552, name:'xxxbook2'},{id:264, name:'book3'}];
const found2 = data2.find(({ id, name }) => id === 552 && name === 'book2');
console.log(found2);    // undefined
console.log(!!found2);  // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript's array method of some will return a boolean if any of the elements inside the array pass the test given to the method. Here this code iterates over the array checks if any element's id is 552 and name is 'book2'. If it finds any element to pass this test it will return true otherwise false.

```js
// Array this.state.allBooks 
const books = [{id:133, name:'book1'}, {id:552, name:'book2'}, {id:264, name:'book3'},]

let isObjIn = books.some(book => book.id === 552 && book.name === 'book2');
console.log(isObjIn); // logs true
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted when I started to write the answer there were no ans. interesting.

Comment: Your answer is correct but it's not very useful to the OP without an explanation of how it works and why you chose to do it that way.

Comment: Thank you very much Pointy. I will make sure to add exp.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use map function,

```
let state:any = {};
let boolValue:boolean = false;
state.allBooks = [
  {id:133, name:'book1'},
  {id:552, name:'book2'},
  {id:264, name:'book3'}
];
state.allBooks.map(e=>{
  if(e.id == '552' && e.name == 'book2'){
    boolValue = true;
  }
});
console.log(boolValue)
```

here is a working example [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dbs5do)

Comment: Why would you use `.map()` instead of `.some()`? The `.some()` method is exactly what this question calls for. The `.map()` method is for making a new array with a 1-1 mapping of original values to new values; that's where the name comes from.